# How to match everything up to the second occurrence of a character?

Tags: regex

So my string looks like this:

```
Basic information, advanced information, super information, no information
```

I would like to capture everything up to second comma so I get:

```
Basic information, advanced information
```

What would be the regex for that?

I tried: `(.*,.*),` but I get

```
Basic information, advanced information, super information,
```

Comment: up to and including, or up to but not including?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this
- The best way would be using group and repetition like this: ^([^,]*,){1}[^,]*    (This way you can match any number of time sections ending with a comma without repeating yourself. Explanation is below)
- Another way would be to remove greediness like this: (.*?,.*?),
- A third way would be like Laurence said. 

The last 2 solutions should only be used if you have only a limited number of sections with comma

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This will capture up to but not including the second comma:

```
[^,]*,[^,]*
```

English translation:

- `[^,]*` = as many non-comma characters as possible
- `,` = a comma
- `[^,]*` = as many non-comma characters as possible

`[...]` is a character class. `[abc]` means "a or b or c", and `[^abc]` means anything but a or b or c.

Comment: @skajfes: yes, I tested it (and the previous one too).

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit quick on the trigger there. I removed the downvote.

Comment: @skajfes: thanks. The old one was unnecessarily complicated -- I'm not sure why I used a negative assertion for the second half when a plain old negative character class works just as well here.

Comment: Ahh got the new one, much better

Comment: So here you instruct not to match a comma [^,]* but match everything else until you get 1 comma and then include everything after but stop at next comma?

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves +1 Thank you very much for your awesome reply. It does help a lot.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: https://regex101.com/r/hAgH68/1

Comment: @jzadra it appears to be working at that link, but what's confusing is that regex101 shows all matches, not just the first match. You can change the regex to `^[^,]*,[^,]*` to anchor it at the beginning, or in your code use a routine that only returns the first match (eg: `re.match` rather than `re.findall` in Python).

Answer (score 7):

You could try `^(.*?,.*?),`
The problem is that `.*` is greedy and matches maximum amount of characters. The ? behind * changes the behaviour to non-greedy.

You could also put the parenthesis around each .*? segment to capture the strings separately if you want.

Comment: Almost works, gets me: Basic information, advanced information, (comma at the end)

Comment: This also matches the second comma. It's unclear from the question whether that's ok or not -- he says he wants "Basic information, advanced information" but perhaps he means captured by the capture group, not captured by the whole regex.

Comment: You have the parenthesis that should capture everything but the comma at the end.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a DRY approach, like this:

```
^([^,]*,){1}[^,]*
```

This way you can match everything until the ***n*** occurrence of a character without repeating yourself except for the last pattern.

Although in the case of the original poster, the group and repetition of the group is useless, I think this will help others who need to match more than 2 times the pattern.

Explanation:

- **^** From the start of the line
- **([^,]*,)** Create a group matching everything except the comma character until it meets a comma.
- **{1}** Count the previous pattern **(the number of times you need)-1**. So if you need 2 put 1, if you need 20 put 19.
- **[^,]*** Repeat the pattern one last time without the tailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
(.*?,.*?),.*
```

[Link to the solution](https://regex101.com/r/yFZvGI/1)