# Regex for finding the second occurrence of a character in a dynamic string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am generating URLs for multiple keywords and i want to remove the second occurrence of the character '&' in the given URL.

I am very new to regex thing and definitely not good at it.

Right now I am just using the indexOf() method and passing the character but it will take the first occurrence. I want the second occurrence but for keywords with the different lengths, it will be at a different position.

suppose if the custom URL is like: 
'https://www.bing.com/search?q=something+something+something+something&mkt=en-IN&organic=True&ads=False&snippet=False'

I want the new URL to be like this:
'https://www.bing.com/search?q=something+something+something+something&mkt=en-IN'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match everything up to the second occurrence of a character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349946/how-to-match-everything-up-to-the-second-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const regex = /(.*?&.*?)&.*/;
const str = `https://www.bing.com/search?q=something+something+something+something&mkt=en-IN&organic=True&ads=False&snippet=False`;


const result = str.replace(regex, '$1');
```

The regular expression searches everything before the second "&" and replaces the original string with this match.