# A regex pattern that matches all words starting from a word with an s and stopping before a word that starts with an s

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to capture words in a string such that the first word starts with an s, and the regex stops matching if the next word also starts with an s.

For example. I have the string " Stack, Code and StackOverflow". I want to capture only " Stack, Code and " and not include "StackOverflow" in the match.

This is what I am thinking:

1. Start with a space followed by an s.
2. Match everything except if the group is a space and an s (I'm using negative lookahead).

The regex I have tried:

```
(?<=\s)S[a-z -,]*(?!(\sS))
```

I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. I adapted the regex from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349985/20473839). You can also test it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/jFkSmf/1).  I have also included a non-regex solution. I basically track the first occurrence of a word starting with an 's' and the next word starting with an 's' and get the words in that range.

```
import re

teststring = " Stack, Code and StackOverflow"
extractText = re.search(r"(\s)[sS][^*\s]*[^sS]*", teststring)

print(extractText[0])

#non-regex solution
listwords = teststring.split(' ')

# non regex solution
start = 0
end = 0
for i,word in enumerate(listwords):
    if word.startswith('s') or word.startswith('S'):
        if start == 0:
            start = i
        else:
            end = i
            break

newstring = " " + " ".join([word for word in listwords[start:end]])
print(newstring)
```

##### Output

```
 Stack, Code and
 Stack, Code and
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both your answer and the one above solve exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use for example a capture group:

```
(S(?<!\S.).*?)\s*S(?<!\S.)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `S(?<!\S.)` Match `S` and assert that to the left of the `S` there is not a whitespace boundary
  - `.*?` Match any character, as few as possible
- `)` Close group
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `S(?<!\S.)` Match `S` and assert that to the left of the `S` there is not a whitespace boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m2lnMU/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RwAFqy).

Example code:

```
import re

pattern = r"(S(?<!\S.).*?)\s*S(?<!\S.)"
s = "Stack, Code and StackOverflow"
m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
Stack, Code and
```

---

Another option using a lookaround to assert the `S` to the right and not consume it to allow multiple matches after each other:

```
 S(?<!\S.).*?(?=\s*S(?<!\S.))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/URqUv5/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"S(?<!\S.).*?(?=\s*S(?<!\S.))"
s = "Stack, Code and StackOverflow test Stack"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Stack, Code and', 'StackOverflow test']
```

Comment: @Izhar Do you want multiple matches in the same string?

Comment: I actually want to capture only the last match in a string. So, in the above example, I want only "StackOverflow test".

I am working on extracting acronym-expansion pair in a sentence. For example, if I have the sentence:
"Can be conducted by capillary electrophoresis-mass spectrometry (CE-MS)".

This is my approach:
1) Start regex at the acronym: (CE-MS)
2) Using regex lookbehind, match everything but stop at the first word that starts with the initial character in the acronym (in this case C). So ideally, I would stop at the word "capillary".

Comment: However, I had issues implementing this, but your solution definitely helped. I still have some rare false positives where the match is more words than the acronym stands for, but I'm willing to accept that.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to improve my approach or come up with something totally new.

Comment: @Izhar Can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: I utilized your answer and the one above and came up with the following regex.  (?<!{p0})(?<= ){p0}[a-z -]*{p1}?[a-z ]*\s?(?<=){pl}[a-z ]*\s(?<=)\({pattern}\) where {p0} is the 1st char in the pattern, {p1} the 2nd, and {pl} the last. Currently it has a success rate of 92%, but fails on some inputs (example strings shown in the regex window) [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdt0iw/1)